# Why Visual Studio allow me to use private members in a template function (C++)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, oop, templates

I'm a little bit confused about strange behavior of Visual Studio.

```
class Test
{
private:
    int x;
};

void func()
{
    Test t;
    t.x; // VS shows error here
}
```

[Syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkM3x.png)

This code does not compile because I'm trying to access to private member `x`

But in case of template function VS says that everything is OK and lets me to access `x`

```
class Test
{
private:
    int x;
};

template <class T>
void func()
{
    Test t;
    t.x; // No error
}
```

[No error with template function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhl40.png)

[VS shows me private fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWNKh.png)

If I call this template function the result will be the compile time error, and I understand why. But I can't understand why VS don't show me error in the editor window. There is a case when this function will work? Or it is just a bug in VS editor?

Comment: Do you instantiate your `func<T>()` function template? If not, compiler simply ignores it.

Comment: Until the method is called, this method is not even compiled. This is perhaps why VS do not show any error.

Comment: The little squiggles in the editor are from Intelisense, which does not actually do a full compile of your code every time. It always struggles with templates for some reason (although, for me it shows errors that aren't actually errors normally).

Comment: Yep, if i call this function it will be an error, and I know that compiler will ignore this function if I will not use it. But it is strange why VS thinks that it is normal to access this private member, like it's a friend function of Test class.

Comment: @GlebSkripnikov: This is a known weak area where Visual Studio is improving, so it helps to post the VS version you are using, and which C++ standard setting you are using with VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A template function isn't a function until the template is instantiated (it's a blueprint for producing functions).

In order to generate an error VS always tells you what the actual template parameters are. Since you do not instantiate it with anything yet there is no way to create that error message (technical reasons may be a different matter though).

Once you start using your template for something you should get the compile error.

*This is Visual Studio specific though.* Other compilers will give the correct error here since `Test::x` isn't a dependent name. This is a known weak area where Visual Studio is improving.

Comment: Correct explanation, but note that this is Visual Studio specific. Other compilers will give the correct error here. `Test::x` is not a dependent name (unrelated to `T`).

Comment: @MSalters *"Other compilers will give the correct error here."* - [gcc compiles just fine](https://godbolt.org/z/gocagN)